# How to align a element inside parent div with bottom 100%

Tags: css

I have a small issue with which I'm struggling.

I need to align a element to the top of a percent div with bottom: 100% but I can't get it to align within the parent div.

So what I need is bottom: 0% to be aligned with the bottom of a div and bottom: 100% to be aligned with the top.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmAEx/

I want the gray bar in that sample to be aligned to top: using 'bottom' 100%

Comment: make a fiddle to show your problem

Comment: more text and less code..please provide the code you have tried so far..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It don't really understand what you mean with `bottom: 100%`, maybe you mean `bottom: 0;`?

Also see [your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/GmAEx/10/).

=== UPDATE ===

Thanks for the comment, I think now I know what are you want to get. The problem is, that `bottom: 100%` for the 'slider handle' means that it is completly outside the parent div.

Add a wrapper around the parent `div` which has the complete height minus the height of the slider handle and add a padding with height of slider handle. Replace the parent height with `100%`. Move the `with`, `background-color` and `margin-top` to the wrapper too.

Also see `bottom: 0%`: [updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zB6RA/1/)

Also see `bottom: 100%`: [updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zB6RA/2/)

Comment: Im using jquery UI to make a slider. It uses bottom 100:% when the slider is at the top.

Comment: The thing is that it's the bottom of the .child that is relative in this case.. so the bottom 100% will tell the bottom of the .child to go 100% up in the parent, which is on top of the parent..  

I see the problem, I'm still pulling my hair for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is being dynamically generated, otherwise you'd just use `top: 0` instead.

If this is the case, then you probably have something like:

```
child.style.bottom = y+"%";
```

In which case, it's a simple matter of adding:

```
child.style.marginTop = (child.offsetHeight/100*y)+"px";
```